# How do I cycle a JS function in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a title on my website and I want to change a word in the title every 2 seconds. I did this by putting an html element in Elementor with the following code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <h1> Test sentence <span id="change_title_text">WordToChange</span></h1>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
    var messages = [],
        index = 0;

    messages.push('Word 1');
    messages.push('Word 2');

    function cycle() {
        $('#change_title_text').html(messages[index]);
        index++;

        if (index === messages.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(cycle, 2000);
    }

    cycle();
});
</script>
```

This works fine and as expected. However, I would really like to keep all my JS code in a file to make it easier to find and to keep the code more structured. I have a custom JS file which has code since before which works, so I know that it runs properly. I tried to copy/paste the code from the html element to my custom JS file like this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
$(function () {
    var messages = [],
        index = 0;

    messages.push('Word 1');
    messages.push('Word 2');

    function cycle() {
        $('#change_title_text').html(messages[index]);
        index++;

        if (index === messages.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(cycle, 2000);
    }

    cycle();
});
```

And the JS file is loaded in my child themes functions.php like this:

```
function custom_js_script_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_script('mycustomjs', CHILD_THEME_URI . '/assets/js/my-custom-js.js', array(), '1.0.0', false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_js_script_enqueue');
```

What do I have to do to make the JS code run as in the html element? I tried to move JS from footer to header by changing the last element of wp_enqueue_script to false but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to include jquery with your javascript, you should use wordpress to define jQuery as a dependency to your custom script.

```
function custom_js_script_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_script(
       'mycustomjs', 
       CHILD_THEME_URI . '/assets/js/my-custom-js.js', 
       array('jquery'),
       '1.0.0'
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_js_script_enqueue');
```

you can read about all of the [libraries available in wordpress here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-and-js-libraries-included-and-registered-by-wordpress).

Your script should not include the jquery include and use `jQuery` directly rather than the `$` shortcut.

The contents of `my-custom-js.js` should be as follows:

```
jQuery(function () {
    var messages = [],
        index = 0;

    messages.push('Word 1');
    messages.push('Word 2');

    function cycle() {
        jQuery('#change_title_text').html(messages[index]);
        index++;

        if (index === messages.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(cycle, 2000);
    }

    cycle();
});
```

That will make sure jquery is loaded in the page before your script runs.

And then in Elementor at a HTML widget to the page with the html:

```
<div>
    <h1> Test sentence <span id="change_title_text">WordToChange</span></h1>
</div>
```

This runs correctly in my Elementor test page.

Alternatively...

you don't really need to use jquery for this, just use vanilla javascript. use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21814964/5393746) event.  If you change your script to the following and it should work without any dependencies:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var messages = [],
        index = 0,
        element = document.getElementById('change_title_text');


    messages.push('Word 1');
    messages.push('Word 2');

    function cycle() {
        element.innerHTML = messages[index];
        index++;

        if (index === messages.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(cycle, 2000);
    }

    cycle();
});
```

Here it is working in a code pen: https://codepen.io/timrross/pen/dyeEoKE

No need for jquery.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure where your fadein/out comes from as $.html() just swaps the content (see https://api.jquery.com/html/) Do you have any other jquery plugins enabled? 
I just implmented the code in an elementor page, and I can see that in my example I need to use `jQuery` rather than `$`. But it works fine. No fading though. I've updated my example with the working code.